# Slice a video recorded using videojs in angular2

Tags: angular, ffmpeg, video.js, videojs-record

I am using videojs plugin in angular2 to record the video. I want to allow user to slice the recorded video in particular time frame user want by selecting time.

Is there any functionality available in videojs to slice a recorded video? if yes then what options we have to set for it?

If that type of functionality is not available then is there any plugin available in angular2 which I can use for allow user to slice a video that means select a time frame by simple slider, and can preview that selected part?

In backend I had setup FFMPEG to cut slice the video but I want to allow user to select a time frame and preview it in frontend angular2 so need plugin for angular2 to slice the video and preview.

Comment: Well, you CAN do what you describe, just by using the progress-bar that is built-in the the VIDEO-JS viewer.  (As you hover along, the time-values appear, and then you can drag that round slider-button to start point and just view from there. (But, that's probably messier and less accurate than what you have in mind.)  Another approach, would be to built your own external slider, and have it it just display a section of thumbnails (smaller/less-resolution images), such as I've done here:  https://weasel.firmfriends.us/Private3-BB/   But, maybe not that either..  Can you be more specific?

Comment: Or, by 'slice' do you mean to actually RECORD into a separate file, a sub-section of a video?  Some discussion of that here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55832898/is-anyone-integrated-videojs-record-with-angular-7

Comment: @Dave I need to sice the video that means once video recorded, for ex. recorded video of 3 min and now I want to select any 60 min by provide starting time and ending time ex. 1:43 to 3:00. once user select it user can view the preview of that selected minutes by clicking play button in player, I have FFMPEG in back-end to cut that video.
But in front end how I can provide selection functionality to user?